# How to run shell commands after vim commands in command mode?

Tags: bash, vim, shell

I know how to run shell comands in vim with `:!` bang syntax, But how can I done it after vim commands? for example `:w!; !echo "some stuff"`? I cannot make semicolon and continue with bang. So is there a possibility do mix vim/shell commands, or the only way to do it is separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pipe character:

```
:w|!echo "some stuff"
```

You can find more about it in `:help :bar`.

Comment: Why the `|`. Vim documentation `:help |`says only about pipe as `screen column` motion, but no use in ex mode

Comment: @Herdsman Yeah, but see edit.